# using Collect Code to track user's web history (cookies)

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

It was my understanding that collect code can be inserted into web pages so that we can capture tracking data / cookie information about individuals.  I understand that it will not be possible to link the web traffic history to a subscriber until you actually capture e.g. the email address of the individual, but I'm getting stuck on how to see the tracked data other than through the web / analytics dashboard.  Do we have to set up some functionality in order to get the tracking data into e.g. a data extension?

Answer (score 1):

**Update - spring 2018:**

It is now possible to enable the integration of this tracking data into PI_ and IGO_ data extensions, without involving Salesforce Services. You can enable it yourself, once you find the settings here:

Personalization Builder > Predictive Email > Status > Settings icon > Data Extension Settings

--- end of update----

I know this is a late reply, but hopefully it might help others in same situation. You need to contact Salesforce to enable integration between web tracking app (formerly known as IGO Digital) and Marketing Cloud. This is a standard service provided through your SFMC Account Executive. Once this is in place, you will be able to see the data in a number of Data Extensions (starting with IGO_) in your Marketing Cloud instance.

Brgds
Lukas

Comment: Hello, is there any documentation available regarding this functionality. I have  to evaluate the feature but I am not finding anything. I.e. What data extensions will be activated, How will the visitor be linked to an existing subscriber?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @Dr.Xavier. There is a number of system Data Extensions available, all starting with IGO_ and PI_. They are readily available in all accounts provisioned after May 2016. If the account you are working on is older than this, please contact Salesforce Support to enable them. As I wrote above, you will have to contact them anyway, to provision the integration between collect code and the Data Extensions. The IGO_PROFILES relates to your contact by email address, and links to all visited products or articles and their attributes (across all PI DEs)

Comment: There is unfortunately no official documentation on these features, and it took me some trial and error to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Lukas L. I need to confirm the following scenarios with cloud collect. 1. I can identify an web visitor and link his/her behaviour to an existing subscriber. 2. I can record in data extension behaviour of anonymous visitors (visitors that I cannot link to existing subscribers)

Comment: This is correct. Once customer is identified (using _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "youremail@domain.com"}]);) you can link the behaviour to the profile in Contact Builder. Read about all Data Extensions in PI here:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/personalization_builder/personalization_builder_integrations/integration_with_contact_builder/

Comment: Hi Lukas, I'm wondering: Is catalog configuration required to enable the use of all of those data extensions or is data like Page Views available without that?

Comment: Hi @StephandePaly - you can enable the integration yourself, but before you can do so, ensure prerequisites are in place: Please ensure you've uploaded a catalog.
Please ensure that data collection has been set up and a recommendation page has been created.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The customer doesn't want to use recommendations. It's only about the tracking data and ways to use it for segmentation. Especially page views. A catalog is going to be quite an issue because the web page has some structural complexity (e.g. currently 6 category levels) and sorting that out will take a long time.

Comment: You just need a very basic catalog, uploaded with only few fields and items. Keeping it updated can be done from JS using streaming updates. Even when not using recommendations, the catalogue is needed. If page ID is not found in the catalogue, the page view is not registered in IGO_VIEWS

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll see what is possible